# Changing scene by sliding your finger on the screen in Corona

Tags: coronasdk, slide, touch-event

I am trying to change scenes with director class by sliding finger on the screen. However, it is not working properly. The scenes are not coming in order. Can you please examine my code and tell me if I miss something? I tried to print currentNumberNo for debugging and found out that it is changing twice when I slide my cursor once. What can be the reason?

main.lua

```
local director = require "director"
--GLOBALS--
W = display.contentWidth
H = display.contentHeight
room={"kitchen", "bedroom", "bathroom"}
currentRoomNo = 1

director:changeScene("kitchen")
```

kitchen.lua:

```
module(..., package.seeall)
local director = require "director"

function new()

group = display.newGroup()

local bg = display.newRect(0,0,W,H); bg:setFillColor(255,250,30)
group:insert(bg)

---[[
local function slide(event) 
if event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
    local dif = event.xStart-event.x
    if dif> 30 then
        if currentRoomNo==#room then
            currentRoomNo = 1
        else
            currentRoomNo = currentRoomNo + 1
        end
    director:changeScene(room[currentRoomNo])
    elseif dif< -30 then
        if currentRoomNo==1 then
            currentRoomNo = #room
        else
            currentRoomNo = currentRoomNo - 1
        end
    director:changeScene(room[currentRoomNo])
    end 
end
return true
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", slide)
--]]
return group

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
module(..., package.seeall)
local director = require "director"

function new()
local isChanging = false
group = display.newGroup()

local bg = display.newRect(0,0,W,H); bg:setFillColor(255,250,30)
group:insert(bg)

---[[
local function slide(event) 
if ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" ) and isChanging == false then
    local dif = event.xStart-event.x
    if dif> 30 then
        if currentRoomNo==#room then
            currentRoomNo = 1
        else
            currentRoomNo = currentRoomNo + 1
        end
    director:changeScene(room[currentRoomNo])
    isChanging = true
    elseif dif< -30 then
        if currentRoomNo==1 then
            currentRoomNo = #room
        else
            currentRoomNo = currentRoomNo - 1
        end
    director:changeScene(room[currentRoomNo])
    isChanging = true
    end 
end
return true
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", slide)
--]]
return group

end
```

Comment: I've tried this but now it's resetting the currentRoomNo in new scene so it won't get to the third scene because currentRoomNo is 1 in main.lua and in second room(currentRoomNo should be 2 but 1) so it increases to 2 which is itself again. Can't we modify the currentRoomNo in main.lua? Isn't it global?

Comment: Oh, I see now. It's problematic to change a variable which is created in main.lua. When you try to change it in another module, corona behaves like you are trying to create a new value with same name. So basically, you are creating a new variable in this module. There is a simple way to fix this: You should create your variable in main lua file and also you should create a function which changes the value of this variable, so you can achieve what you want.